# (Big O) Finding the number of iterations in a nested loop

Tags: loops, big-o

By this logic why are there n(n-1)/2 iterations for the inner loop? If the sum of 1 to N results in n/2*(n+1), then why doesn't the sum of 1 to N-1 result in n/2*(n)?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Subtract 1 from *both* occurrences of *n*. n×(n+1)/2 decreases to (n-1)×(n+1-1)/2 which equals (n-1)×n/2. Swap the two terms and you have n×(n-1)/2.

Answer (score 0):

The sum of integers from 1...N = N*(N+1)/2.

Therefore the sum of integers from `1...(N-1)` = `(N-1)*(N)/2` and not `N/2*N` as you claim.

Either way, the big-O remains `O(n^2)`.